# Rails ajax chat app missing a template for this request format and variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I have a chat feature in a rails application im working on. Im using ajax to send messages. I decided to add paperclip onto my messages table, so you can send images in chat, but when i press enter the image appears for a second, its stored into the database, and then the page throws an error

```
    MessagesController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []
```

when i refresh the page the images shows up fine in the chat so i know the form submitted.

chatrooms.cofee

```
    $(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
     $("#new_message").on "keypress", (e) ->
       if e && e.keyCode == 13
         e.preventDefault()
         $(this).submit()
```

messages_controller.rb

```
   class MessagesController < ApplicationController
     before_action :authenticate_user!
     before_action :set_chatroom


    def create
      message = @chatroom.messages.new(message_params)
      message.user = current_user
      message.save
      MessageRelayJob.perform_later(message)
   end

   private

    def set_chatroom
     @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
    end

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body, :image)
   end
 end
```

show.html.erb

```
    <%= render 'side_nav' %>

    <div class = "container-fluid">
     <div class = "col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
    <p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <%= @chatroom.name %>
    </p>

     <div data-behavior="messages" data-chatroom-id='<%= @chatroom.id %>'>
     <% @messages.each do |message| %>
     <%= render message  %>
     <% end %>
    </div>

      <%= form_for [@chatroom, Message.new], remote: true , multipart:  true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :body , rows: 1 , class: "form-control", autofocus:true%>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
```

sorry for the bad formatting, im new to stack overflow, but you can add as many chatrooms as you like, and im using ajax to send the messages. Im not sure if i need to include some sort of extra code to handle images. There is no error when sending basic strings, just the paperclip images.

Comment: so... do you have a `create.html.erb` ? because that is what Rails is telling you it is expecting...
Alternatively - you can redirect to the show page at the end of the create action :)

Comment: @Tarn East no i rendered the form in the show.html.erb, but i do have a create.js.erb with just this one line $("#new_message")[0].reset(). Are you saying do a redirect_to show ? i dont want to be redirected out of the chat

Comment: The error you are getting is saying it is missing a create-template with format html. if rendering that is not what you want... then you need to change how you *call* the create action. eg if you want it to be asking for the JS-version... then you need to make sure that `format: js` goes into the link/form request. :)

Comment: actually @Tarn East your absolutely right i added redirect_to "show" , and that fixed the problem. Cant believe i didnt thank of that. thanks.

Comment: I'll make that into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is saying it is missing a create-template with format html. so... do you have a `create.html.erb`?
Because that is what Rails is telling you it is expecting...

If rendering that is not what you want... then you need to change how you call the create action. eg if you want it to be asking for the JS-version of the `create.js.erb` template... then you need to make sure that `format: js` goes into the link/form request.

Alternatively - you can redirect to the show page at the end of the create action :)

Answer (score 2):

Your create action will **render** by default. Since you don't have a template and don't want it to render you need to override it.

Instead of:

```
def create
  message = @chatroom.messages.new(message_params)
  message.user = current_user
  message.save
  MessageRelayJob.perform_later(message)
end
```

do something like :

```
def create
  message = @chatroom.messages.new(message_params)
  message.user = current_user
  if message.save
    MessageRelayJob.perform_later(message)
    render json: {success: "message sent", error: false}, status: 200
  else
    render json: {success: false, error: true}, status: 422
  end
end
```

eventually your browser clients will want some feedback as to whether or not the message was saved/sent.

Comment: i tried your answer, and the error did go away thanks , but i'm redirected to a new page displaying the JSON response. Is there a way i can stay on the chat page , since it is a chat feature @Blair Anderson

Comment: change `remote: true` to `data: {remote: true}` on your form

Comment: your form is submitting with HTML instead of JSON. you can also change your coffee-script to submit via AJAX instead of using `$(this).submit()`

Comment: changing the controller to redirect to "show" seemed to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your MessagesController you need to add the redirect in this way. "In the last line redirect_to chatroom_path(@chatroom) you redirect correctly"

```
def create
 message = @chatroom.messages.new(message_params)
 message.user = current_user
 message.save
 MessageRelayJob.perform_later(message)
 redirect_to chatroom_path(@chatroom)
end
```